# Determine the number of the first of the columns that contains at least one zero element

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Here is what i tried:

```
import numpy as np

np.matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 0],
                      [1, 5, 8],
                      [4, 7, 9]
                      ])


print(np.where(np.matrix == 0))
```

Here's what i got:

```
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64))
```

I don't know how i can print the column number. As a result I have to get an integer ("*column 3*" as in the example)

Answer (score 1):

`np.where` returns multiple arrays, one for each dimension in your array. If you run `np.matrix.ndim`, you'll see it returns `2`, so `np.where` will return 2 arrays:

```
row_indexes, column_indexes = np.where(np.matrix == 0)
print(f'Row number: {row_indexes[0] + 1}')
print(f'Column number: {column_indexes[0] + 1}')
```

That said, you might be looking for `np.argwhere`:

```
row_index, column_index = np.argwhere(np.matrix == 0)[0]
print(f'Row number: {row_index + 1}')
print(f'Column number: {column_index + 1}')
```

Output for both:

```
Row number: 1
Column number: 3
```

(Side note: you shouldn't store your matrix in `np.matrix`. Instead name it something like `matrix` or `np_matrix`. `np.matrix` puts in inside of the numpy module, which is bad practice.)

Comment: I think it's `column_indexes.min()`, because the second array is ordered by the sorted row_indexes.

Comment: @Michael feel free to edit if you think that's better.

Comment: It's always hard to tell with sample data that only contains the simplest case.